# Difference among always_ff, always_comb, always_latch and always

Tags: system-verilog

I am totally confused among these 4 terms: `always_ff`, `always_comb`, `always_latch` and `always`. How and for what purpose can these be used?

Answer (score 51):

**`always`** is the main type of process from Verilog, the other is an `initial` which is ran once at the start of a simulation.

**`always_ff @(posedge clk)`** :
Represents a flip-flop (ff), the process is triggered (executed) on every positive edge of the clock. This replaces `always @(posedge clk)`.

```
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
  a <= b;
end
```

**`always_latch`** : is for representing latches.

Usage would be :

```
always_latch begin
  if (enable) begin
     a_latch <= something;
  end
  //No else clause so a_latch's value
  //is not always defined, so it holds its value
end
```

This replaces :

```
always @* begin
  if (enable) begin
     a_latch = something;
  end
  //No else clause so a_latch's value
  //is not always defined, so it holds its value
end
```

**`always_comb`**:
Is for combinatorial logic, it is replacement for `always @*` when you do not want a latch. Now we can now differentiate our design intent between when we want and do not want latches.

The SystemVerilog names `always_ff`, `always_latch` and `always_comb` have stricter criteria for when they are triggered, this means the chance for RTL to Gate level (post synthesis) mismatch is reduced. It does mean they are not 100% equivalent to their `always @` counterpart and may change some simulation behaviour.

Comment: `always_comb` is not equivalent to `always @*`, and you should no longer be using `always @*`. The biggest reason is that `always @*` does not work when constants or parameters are involved in the logic. They do not generate events to trigger the execution of the block. `always_comb` guarantees execution at time 0.

Comment: Thanks @dave_59 I tried to cover the exact equality with my last paragraph. They are SystemVerilog and IPs are often design to be backwards compatible with Verilog, so usage of `always @*` will continue. Considering how many beginners post questions with manual sensitivity list I think we have a way to go before `always_comb` becomes the norm.

Comment: Yep, just think how long it is taking people to switch from using comment pragmas like `//synthesis translate on`  to using ` `ifdef SYNTHESIS`. It's been over 25 years since `ifdef was added to Verilog.

Comment: @Morgan: The IEEE standard uses `always_latch` with non-blocking assignments. Any specific reason you are using blocking assignments in your reply?

Comment: @Ari I see `always_latch` as an extension of `always @*`. `<=` Models flip-flop behaviour and when a latch is open it is transparent so I think `=` is more appropriate. and I had not noticed that they use non-blocking (`<=`) in the LRM.