# If always_ff = always @ (posedge clk), then why write always_ff @ (posedge clk)?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, fpga

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101717/difference-among-always-ff-always-comb-always-latch-and-always) post, the question is seemingly addressed, but it leaves some room for questions about how this works in practice.

It is easy to understand why `always @ (posedge clk)` makes logic from flip flops (because flip flops are updated every clock cycle), but why differentiate with a different "always" construct?

Is there any chance that `always @ (posedge clk)` won't create logic from flip flops somehow? Is this more important in digital design for ASICs than in FPGAs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If always_ff = always @ (posedge clk)

That is an incorrect assumption.

Just like  with `always`, `always_ff` can have different sensitivity lists.  Here are a few examples:

```
always_ff @(posedge clk)
always_ff @(negedge spi_clock)
always_ff @(posedge reset or negedge nClk)
```

Any signal name can be used for the clock signal, an asynchronous reset signal can also be optionally specified, and any combination of polarities can be used.

Both `always` and `always_ff` keywords can be used to model sequential logic (such as flip-flops).  Both can infer flip-flops for synthesis of ASICs or FPGAs.

`always_ff` was introduced into the language to offer different semantics.  It conveys more specific design intent than the general `always` (which can also be used to infer combinational logic).

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 9.2.2.4 *Sequential logic always_ff procedure*.

Another advantage:

> Software tools should perform additional checks to warn if the
> behavior within an `always_ff` procedure does not represent sequential
> logic.

[See also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemVerilog#Procedural_blocks)